# Can I rely on Go's `crypto/rand` package to give me unique random string?

Tags: go, cryptography, unique, uniqueidentifier, secret-key

I want to generate 32 characters long `unique` `unguessable` alphanumeric secret keys. The secret key will be an identifier for my system and will be used to look up information.

While searching the web I stumbled upon the `crypto/rand` package of `Go`. Which is able to generate random alphanumerics with the help of underline system calls. But I am concerned that the value returned by the `crypto/rand` package might produce a non-unique string down the line.

Can anyone clarify if I can rely on the `crypto/rand` package for the job?

Comment: The package description: “Package rand implements a cryptographically secure random number generator.” Tells you what you need. It’s kind of important that package works as described, so there’s no reason to doubt the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Of course with randomly generated tokens, there is always the possibility of generating a duplicate token. There are standards such as [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (excluding v4) that use other methods to try to "guarantee" uniqueness of each identifier. These methods do not truly obviate the possibility of collisions, they just shift the failure modes. For example, UUID1 relies on [uniqueness of MAC addresses](https://superuser.com/q/968340/1153060), which is a whole issue of its own.

If you are not limited by the size of your tokens, you can easily pick a sufficiently large number of bits that the probability of collisions becomes so small that it is completely dwarfed by countless other failure modes (such as programmer error, cosmic rays, a mass global extinction event, etc.).

Very approximately, if you have a true random key length of N bits, you can generate 2^(N/2) keys before having a 50% chance of seeing collisions. See the Wikipedia page for [UUID#Collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) for a more general formula.

Comment: As the OP wants 32 characters long unique alphanumeric keys I assume a key is represented as a 32-byte hex string. Thus the underlying random number is 128-bit (16-byte) following the OP's intent to use crypto/rand. This should be taken into account for estimating or calculating probability of collision.

Answer (score 4):

I think, for this type of thing, you should use [UUID](https://github.com/google/uuid)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    id := uuid.New()
    fmt.Println(id.String())
}
```

Comment: It's quite confusing though, it states this generates RFC4122 uuids. Paragraph 6 in the rfc states this is not cryptographically secure. I don't know go to enough detail, are these generated with a CSPRNG?

Comment: @GaborLengyel In this issue, your concerns were discussed https://github.com/google/uuid/issues/77.

Comment: This is a good answer for many purposes, but be aware @T4puSD that you asked for 32 alphanumeric characters, that's about 190 bits of entropy if fully random. A uuid has 122 bits of entropy, significantly less (but still might be enough for many purposes, just something to understand).

Comment: It's worth noting that `uuid.New` defaults to using `uuid.NewRandom`, which in turn uses `crypto/rand`.

Comment: However, crypto/rand does not guarantee for uniqueness of random numbers and the implementation details may also be different for other UUID packages, even though google uuid might be the most popular one out there.

Comment: for a cryptographic keys uniqueness is less important than randomness and unpredictability, so `crypto/rand` is a better approach. But the 190 bits of entropy from a `crypto/rand` sequence of 32 alphanumeric is for all practical purposes unique anyway.

Answer (score 3):

With crypto/rand there is no guarantee that individual random numbers will occur more than once. The probability of this to happen is very low, however, and it may be good enough for your use case. In many cases UUID will be good enough. If you are curious about the probability of duplicate UUIDs, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Universally_unique_identifier) for example.

If you really need *true* uniqueness you may want to combine random numbers with a map to record them, where the number serves as key and the value is a "don't care". While recording the numbers, duplicates can be detected and a new random can be requested in case. However, this approach may introduce a new challenge depending on your setting as the numbers are now kept in memory which is insecure per se. It will also be challenging in terms of complexity  if your use case does not determine the quantity of secrets required during the lifetime of the system.

For me, it really boils down to the question whether the identifiers for your system you use for info lookups are really secrets or you just want unique identifiers which are hard to predict before they occur in the system. Maybe you can elaborate on your use case to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Uniqueness and randomness are not mutually exclusive. For example, the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` _is_ unique, but we can hardly call it random. Additionally, given a theoretical random source, we hypothetically could generate a list of `[1, 81, 44, 1, 9, 2]`. This might be random, but is not unique. Randomness is not unique and uniqueness does not have to be random, therefor, they're not mutually exclusive

Comment: You are right as they are random number generators which yield unique numbers randomly chosen from a set of unique numbers. However, crypto/rand implements CSPRNG which does exclude uniqueness as far as I can tell but I am not a cryptographer.

Comment: @Marcus You are pretty much correct. I  want unique identifiers which are hard to predict by someone even if they managed to get a hands-on the previous value they shouldn't be able to guess what the next unique identifiers will be.

Comment: Another approach to generate unique, hard to predict numbers is to use an encryption function like AES. See https://go.dev/play/p/O7b5S3Lu59l for demo. However, I think the way to go is to use crypto/rand or UUIDv4 for practical (and security) reasons.